# Wine icon not appearing in the applications list

Tags: wine

I installed wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1) via the terminal, I expected a wine icon to appear in the applications, icon still absent. Note that just before I installed a program via the terminal, the icon was in my applications. Any idea how to see the Wine icon?

Comment: You don't usually run wine with an icon, just like you don't click an icon to run Microsoft Windows. Some builtin wine applications you can run are wine notepad and `winecfg`. You usually want to open the terminal and run `wine /path/to/program.exe` to use wine